# Why does pre-sorted index not help me in window function?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, execution-plan, postgresql-13

I am trying to speed up this query. Currently it takes ~6s.

It queries a `TEMP TABLE providers_tam_with_offices_tmp`.

```
select *,
  %(max_providers_to_target_per_territory)s as max_providers,
  case
    when call_point_rank = 1 then
        rank()
        over (partition by team_id, territory_name, call_point_rank order by office_tam desc, account_id, address_key, tam desc, id)
    else NULL
    end as cum_provider_count
from
(
  select *,
    -- We order by `account_id, address_key`, and then by `id` as a tie breaker for
    -- deterministic results.
      rank()
      over (partition by team_id, territory_name, id order by office_tam desc, account_id, address_key,
        tam desc, id ) as call_point_rank
  from
    providers_tam_with_offices_tmp
) a
```

As an experiment, I tried adding this index to `providers_tam_with_offices_tmp`.

```
create index providers_tam_with_offices_tmp_idx on providers_tam_with_offices_tmp
(team_id, territory_name, id, office_tam desc, account_id, address_key,
        tam desc, id );
```

But the query plan shows that this doesn't eliminate the need to sort the table first before calculating the first window function:

[image]

While the utility of this might be questionable, I am interested in the general case of why the optimiser wouldn't spot that there's already an index with *exactly* the sorting required.

Or have I misunderstood how window functions required the data to be organised?

Comment: What if you add on "order by" to your select from providers_tam_with_offices_tmp ?

Comment: you query seems somewhat wrong, please provide a [mre]

Comment: I don't believe the fields of the `PARTITION` clause matter as much as the actual `ORDER BY` clause *possibly*, and therefore when you listed them first in your index creation, you actually prevented it from being a (correctly) covering index. I'd recommend instead indexing on the fields of the `ORDER BY` clause of your **window function**, and using the `INCLUDE` clause of your index to include the fields being `PARTITIONED` like so: `CREATE INDEX idxName ON providers_tam_with_offices_tmp(office_tam desc, account_id, address_key,
        tam desc, id ) INCLUDE (team_id, territory_name, id)`.

Comment: Alternatively you can try creating the index on the fields in the order that they appear in the **Sort** operator of your query plan.

Comment: Please don't upload images for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - can you please paste the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your_query>.

Comment: Execution plans are better presented as text output generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` rather than an image that might hide important details. You can also share such a text output through https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Is `(id)` a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY? If yes, that `call_point_rank` should always be `1`. I don't see how it wouldn't be.

Comment: Also add the `CREATE TABLE` statement and how big (number of rows) it has.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown that it doesn't spot the index, only that it doesn't use it.  If you `set enable_sort = off;` then what happens?

If the table is not well vacuumed and the correlation of team_id with the physical row ordering is low, then reading the index in order will mean hopping all over the table to check that each row from the index is actually visible, leading to the expectation of a lot of costly random IO.  This will be slower (or is expected to be slower) than a nice sequential scan followed by a sequential-IO-optimized sort.